# Problem with color scaling for rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, color-ramp, colormap

I just opened QGIS to be able to make plots and now I notice that I can no longer do color scaling as before.

The problem is shown in the following screenshot.

I uninstalled and installed QGIS several times.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've set transparency to 100%. Just double click on these colors and set it to 0%.

Comment: Or right click  on the color ramp and choose "Edit color ramp" to reset the transparency to 0% (or rather the opacity to 100%)

Comment: Or just select the color ramp new once again

Comment: Thanks to all. All the solution provided worked perfectly. Thanks again